# Send a message from client to server

Tags: html, node.js, client-server

I have a server I wrote in NodeJs which listens to port 1234.
From my client (html) I want to send request to my server and wait for an answer.

I tried to use XMLHttpRequest:

```
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "127.0.0.1:1234";
        var params = "token=22";
        http.open("post", url, true);//"https://www.google.com/search?q=asd"
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 0);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            alert(http.responseText);
        }

        http.ontimeout = function()
        {
            alert("timeout");
        }

        http.timeout=10;
        try
        {
            http.send(null);
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            alert(ex);
        }
```

But I always got exception. The reason was I can't use my own port.

Is There any other way to send request and get respond?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make your life easier and it does get a lot easier with jquery especially when it comes to XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I need to use JSONP to be able use different ports

Comment: if you actually read jquery documentation you will find that it supports jsonp requests